# I am getting a error and i don' t know how to fix it

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*; 

public class factorial
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {    
    int i, j, c;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a factorial");
    i = **in**.nextInt();

      for (j = i; j > 0; j--)
      {
        c = j * i;
      }
      System.out.println( c );
  }
}
```

I am getting an error at the bolded

cannot find symbol

symbol:   variable in

location: class factorial

Comment: Hi awesomesause... i guess, that you need to study more java language. Please try no hard feelings... Now, getting to the question... The line **in**.nextInt() doesn't have sense at all.... do you mean scan.nextInt();

Comment: This question doesnt present any effort, it doesnt compile, and the title is unclear... Sorry if I sound rude but i cant find other words..

Comment: What do you think `in` in `in.nextInt()` is referring to?

Comment: Please read the StackOverflow best practices before asking a question. Your question should be more precise, and you should put in a bit more effort before posting it to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `scan.nextInt()` instead of `in.nextInt()`

The name of your Scanner object is `scan` and not `in`.

The next time you see error message `cannot find symbol`, it means that they cannot identify/recognize the given variable. For beginners, it is most probably due to: forget to declare variable/ typo error in writing variable names.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
i = in.nextInt();
```

it should be:

```
i = scan.nextInt();
```

Variable `in` is not defined, you have called `Scanner` instance as `scan`, so you should use `scan`

Comment: thank you for helping. as u might have noticed i am a novice in java